# How can I set different opacity of edgecolor and facecolor of a patch in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a set of triangles with different orientations and sizes. The inner overlapped shape is what i wanted, which is the darkest area. 
But when I set opacity (alpha) in mpatches.RegularPolygon, the edges become transparent too. 
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should perhaps post some code to make your meaning clear, but from what I understand, you could set the `facecolor` and `edgecolor` separately as (R,G,B,alpha) tuples and set `alpha` for the `edgecolor` equal to 1 to make it opaque if that's what you want. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

triangle1 = Polygon(((0.05,0.1), (0.396,0.1), (0.223, 0.38)),
                    fc=(1,0,0,0.5), ec=(0,0,0,1), lw=2)
triangle2 = Polygon(((0.2,0.2), (0.5,0.4), (0.3, 0.6)),
                    fc=(1,0,0,0.5), ec=(0,0,0,1), lw=2)

ax.add_artist(triangle1)
ax.add_artist(triangle2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And my codes contain many statistics and functions which is too much to make the question clear. I'll post some code next time :))

Comment: If anyone is having trouble getting the patch to respect the edgecolor and facecolor alpha, make sure there is no 'overall' alpha set for the patch. If there is, that value will be used, and the A part of the RGBA for the facecolor will not be respected. The 'overall' alpha can be unset with `patch.set_alpha(None)`.

Comment: As an extra tip, if aiming to use named colors, the trick is with the [to_rgba](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html) function that would allow to do something such as `fc=to_rgba('red', 0.5)`